# Issue with renaming data.table

Tags: r, data.table, rename

So I have the following data.table issue:

```
library(data.table)
dt1<-data.table(V1=runif(10),V2=sample(10),ID=1:10)
     dt1
                V1 V2 ID
     1: 0.26880759 10  1
     2: 0.59148373  9  2
     3: 0.15106101  8  3
     4: 0.64780998  5  4
     5: 0.09067745  7  5
     6: 0.57337100  2  6
     7: 0.17920313  3  7
     8: 0.87948063  4  8
     9: 0.25167438  1  9
    10: 0.82715461  6 10
```

and I am wishing to perform a column rename (except one column, namely the "ID").Although `names(dt1[,-"ID"])` works OK yielding:

```
[1] "V1" "V2"
```

The following command fails:

```
   names(dt1[,-"ID"])<-c("souksou","mouksou")
   Error in -"ID" : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Of course the issue is bypassed via:

```
names(dt1)[!(names(dt1)  %in% "ID")]<-c("souksou","mouksou")

names(dt1)
[1] "souksou" "mouksou" "ID"
```

My question to the community is *why* this happens.

Comment: you need to use `setnames` function

Comment: @Cath elaborate a bit...

Comment: `setnames(dt1, c("V1", "V2"), c("souksou","mouksou"))`. `setnames` is the way to rename columns by reference in a `data.table`

Comment: You can't set the names of a subset. You can only change a subset of the names.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To put my comment into a more visible answer: in [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) , the function `setnames` permits to rename columns (all of them or a subset of them) by reference.

Try `?setnames` to see how it works. Basically, you need to give the function 3 arguments, `x`, `old` and `new`: `x` is your `data.table`, `old` are the names or the indices of the variables you want to rename (if you want to rename all of the variables, `old` can be the new names and you don't need to provide `new`) and `new` is the new column names.

In your example, you need to do:

```
setnames(dt1, c("V1", "V2"), c("souksou","mouksou"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest another way (and maybe a simpler one).

```
names(dt1) = gsub('V1', 'souksou', names(dt1))
names(dt1) = gsub('V2', 'mouksou', names(dt1))
```